# How can I get my Blogger posts to automatically post to Google+

Tags: google-plus, blogger

On my blog, I'd like to have blog entries I post automatically post to google+ too (preferably just the first paragraph or something?). Is there any way to do that?

I've seen a couple of things online, but all of them require an additional manual step of posting to google+ after you've published the blog entry. I frequently use later publishing, so I'm not always sitting at the computer when it is published, so that doesn't quite work?

Other social networks, like Facebook, have an import feed option, where I can say "hey look at this blog feed, whenever something gets added to that feed, post it on facebook." Is something like that integrated into Google+?

Comment: Import feed is no longer available see http://www.facebook.com/help/issues/notes

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing at the moment that will accomplish this *properly* (it may be possible through some script automation) as [Google+ API is currently read only](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

> Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Maybe the reverse is possible if Blogger allows it. It sounds like something Google might be planning to do. See [Use your Google+ profile with your Blogger blogs](http://buzz.blogger.com/2011/10/use-your-google-profile-with-your.html)

Comment: I added another paragraph to my question. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: @McKay as I said above Google+ is read only for API and most users seem to be using it as a separate blogging platform altogether. Facebook import feed option is also removed and replaced with notes as well as I think? 50,000 status limit on characters? (or words?)

Answer (score -1):

**THIS CAN BE DONE**,seriously it took me many days to find.
 ,for this you must have two account,

- twitter
- g +

now you can easily setup blogger to twitter.check dlvr.com or rss method.
now goto www.twoogleplus.com
login with your twitter account
login with your blogger.com account

hurray you done.